# implementing protocol methods in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, uikit

If I have an protocol (say UIPickerViewDataSource) and I implement its required methods, do I need to declare those methods in the header file of my class?

At the moment I'm not doing so and I get a warning of incomplete implementation (although everything works fine). If I do add the required methods in the then I don't get such warning:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```

Is this the correct behaviour? Is it really necessary to add the declaration for required protocol methods in the header file of my class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't. Declaring that the class implements that protocol and implementing the methods is enough. You could still declare them in the header for documentation purposes, though.

Comment: +1 If you specify the implementing protocol in the header, I wouldn't declare them there - same with overridden methods. I do like the grouping with pragmas in the implementation file as Apple suggests.

Comment: Appart from the unnecessity to explicitly specify the protocol methods in the header, I might add that most of the time I find adding those protocol methods to a class header unnecessarily litters the header file and distracts from the methods that make the class "unique".

Comment: Indeed. It's the open specification of what methods your class "exports". And the delegate methods are probably not what you want other people/objects to call directly.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way is to declare that your class implements the protocol. If for instance your class is called `LordSandwichViewController`, then your class interface must look like this:

```
@interface LordSandwichViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource> {
{
}
```

So you don't declare the protocol methods in your class interface, only the protocol.

Comment: To be exact, you use the angle-bracket-delimited portion of the interface declaration to declare that your class *conforms to* the listed protocols. An actual protocol declaration begins with the `@protocol` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Incomplete implementation warnings tell you that you are not implementing all the required methods you are either:

1. Defining in your header.
2. Declaring a method required by a protocol you're conforming to.

Look at what methods it's expecting, and implement those.